# Node.JS HTTP shortcut wrapper

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, rest

The Node.JS HTTP and HTTPS modules only provide `.get` shortcut function, unlike [AngularJS's `$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) which provides them all. I went about creating a `function` that returns one of these shortcut `function`s:

```
'use strict';

var http = require('http');

function httpF(method) {
    return function (options, body_or_cb, cb) {
        if (!cb) {
            cb = body_or_cb;
            body_or_cb = null;
        }
        options['method'] = method;
        if (body_or_cb)
            if (!options)
                options = {'headers': {'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body_or_cb)}};
            else if (!options.headers)
                options.headers = {'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body_or_cb)};
            else if (!options.headers['Content-Length'])
                options.headers['Content-Length'] = Buffer.byteLength(body_or_cb);
        var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
            if (!res)
                return cb(res);
            else if ((res.statusCode / 100 | 0) > 3)
                return cb(res);
            return cb(null, res);
        });
        body_or_cb && req.write(body_or_cb);
        req.end();
        return req;
    };
}
```

It pushes the callback through an `(err, res)` signature also. The idea here is to enable chaining in [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) or use as a [Bluebird promise](http://bluebirdjs.com).

Usage:

```
var httpPOST = httpF('POST');

httpPOST({
    protocol: 'http:',
    host: 'httpbin.org',
    path: '/post',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
}, JSON.stringify({hello: 'world'}), function (err, res) {
    if (err)
        console.error(err.statusCode, err.statusMessage);
    else
        console.info(res.statusCode, res.statusMessage);
});
```

[Original TypeScript](https://gist.github.com/SamuelMarks/d561575d13499c53ebead97e0a51eb04)

Some improvement ideas:

- Use `url.parse` to enable `httpPOST('https://httpbin.org/post', ..` (including use of `https` module)
- Wrap all errors up into something `util.inherits` from `Error`
- Fix bug that stops `async.series` from continuing after failure (even happens with this hack `e ? cb() : cb(null, r)`)

I also submitted this as a [PR](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/5990), but it was rejected (as expected).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You mentioned a bug towards the end, does your code actually work as intended?